# Use function parameters as a variable call

Tags: javascript, jquery

what has already been described in the title, but basically I want to send a function perimeter and use it to call one of the three different variables. Also so it doesn't come to a miss understanding the "$('#'+id)" part of the code works all I need is the correct syntax for the "id =" part (if even possible). And I know there is a workaround but I am trying to minimize code and this seems like the most optimal solution.

my code:

```
<div class="one">
    <p>ime:</p>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <p>kraj:</p>
    <input type="text" id="city">
    <p>starost:</p>
    <input type="text" id="age">
    <p id="one_output"></p>
</div>
```

```
var name = "1";
var city = "2";
var age = "3";

function statement(id) {
    id = $('#'+id+'').val();
    $("#one_output").text("Sem " + name + " in živim v " + city + ". Star sem " + age);
};

$('.one input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    switch($(this).attr("id")) {
        case "name":
            statement(the_id);
            break;
        case "city":
            statement(the_id);
            break;
        case "age":
            statement(the_id);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: just to avoid confusion, you mean "parameter" right? #1 in your function `statement`, you're not using `id` at all #2 the switch and `the_id` could be simply wrote as `statement($(this).attr('id'))` and remove the switch and the `the_id` line completely

Comment: @balexandre i have updated the code for your second point but for your fist point. i use the id in the jquery call ($("#"+id)) but i also want to use it to call the variable defined in the lines 1-3 of my javascrip code, i am hopiing to achive this by having html element ids the same as the javascrip variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I think I finally understood what you're after

so you're passing a variable name and want to dynamically call it, instead of going the `global` way using `this`, I would recommend to do it by having all your vars in just one global one, for example

```
var formInputs = { name: '1', city: '2', age: '3' }
```

and then you can easily read/write them with `formInputs[ var_name_here ]`

so your example, would be written as

```
var formInputs = { name: '1', city: '2', age: '3' }

function statement(name, val) {
    formInputs[name] = val
    var txt = `Sem ${formInputs.name} in živim v ${formInputs.city}. Star sem ${formInputs.age}`
    $("#one_output").text(txt)
}

$('.one input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var elm = $(this)
    statement(elm.attr("id"), elm.val())
})
```

```js
var formInputs = { name: '...', city: '...', age: '...' }

var statement = function(name, val) {
    formInputs[name] = val // assign value to variable
    var txt = `Sem <b>${formInputs.name}</b> in živim v <b>${formInputs.city}</b>. Star sem <b>${formInputs.age}</b>` // the new text
    $("#one_output").html(txt) // output
}

$('.one input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var elm = $(this) // our key element
    statement(elm.attr("id"), elm.val()) // pass id and why not the value, so we dont need the element again
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
    <p>ime: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
    <p>kraj: <input type="text" id="city"></p>
    <p>starost: <input type="text" id="age"></p>
    <p id="one_output"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize your code, you can start by doing this:

```
id = $(`#${id}`).val();
```

Instead of this:

```
id = $('#'+id+'').val();
```

Modify your keyup callback to a more cleaner code:

```
$('.one input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    var myId = $(this).attr("id"));
    var id = $('#'+myId+'').val();
    $("#one_output").text("Sem " + name + " in živim v " + city + ". Star 
    sem " + 
     age);

});
```